# How I can fix TileOutOfRange" locator="TILECOLUMN in GeoServer 2.17.2 WMTS in openlayers v6?

Tags: openlayers, wmts

I am going to use GeoServer WMTS in openlayers and then I found an example in Openlayers website, It seems everything is correct but I get this error:

```
<ExceptionReport xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://geowebcache.org/schema/ows/1.1.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<Exception exceptionCode="TileOutOfRange" locator="TILECOLUMN">
<ExceptionText>Column 21 is out of range, min: 39 max:43</ExceptionText>
</Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

Where should I change in my code, My map zone layers is UTM Zone 38N untill UTM Zone 42N, I chanage EPSG based on UTM zone area but I got 400 bad request again.

```
const projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326');
const projectionExtent = projection.getExtent();
const size = ol.extent.getWidth(projectionExtent) / 256;
const resolutions = new Array(14);
const matrixIds = new Array(14);
for (let z = 0; z < 14; ++z) {
  // generate resolutions and matrixIds arrays for this WMTS
  resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
  matrixIds[z] = "EPSG:4326:" + z;
}

var wmtsLayers=[
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      title:`${layers_}`,
      opacity: 0.7,
      source: new ol.source.WMTS({
        attributions: '...',
        url: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?request=getCapabilities`,
        layer: `${geoServerWs}:${layers_}`,
        matrixSet: 'EPSG:4326',
        format: 'image/png',
        serverType:'geoserver',
        TileLoadFunction:function(tile, src) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.open('GET', src);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(`${geoUserName}` + ':' + `${geoPass}`));
            xhr.onload = function() {
                var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
                tile.getImage().onload = function() {
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
                    
    };
    tile.getImage().src = objectURL;
  };
  xhr.send();
},
        projection: projection,
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
          origin:ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
          resolutions: resolutions,
          matrixIds: matrixIds
        })
      })
    })
  ];
 var wmsLayers=[
     new ol.layer.Tile({
         title:`${layers_}`,
           visible: true,
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
       url: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/${geoServerWs}/wms`,
       params: {'LAYERS': `${geoServerWs}:${layers_}`},
 ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        
        imageLoadFunction: function(image, src) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.open('GET', src);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(`${geoUserName}` + ':' + `${geoPass}`));
            xhr.onload = function() {
                var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
                image.getImage().onload = function() {
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
                    
    };
    image.getImage().src = objectURL;
  };
  xhr.send();
},
     
      
      })
   })
];
 
// The Map
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
       view: new ol.View({
             zoom: 5,
            center:ol.proj.fromLonLat([54.233527,32.343721])
         }),
         
         
        layers: [baselayers,],
       overlays: [overlay],
       
    });
```

*GeoServerWm is name of worksapce.

Comment: Your WMTS is in a global projection EPSG:4326 but does it have global coverage?  If not you can specify an extent in the tilegrid (in EPSG:4326) or in the layer (in view coordinates) to limit requests.

Comment: Sorry I can not understand exacty, this is my area https://epsg.io/2058 I shoud change origin value from ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent), to EPSG:2058 or 400850.81 2581672.08
2075081.32 4567903.78 I changed center view in var map but it doenst work, ciould you please exact places I should change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a EPSG:4326 tilegrid but are only interested in tiles from a smaller region you should use

```
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
      origin:ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
      resolutions: resolutions,
      matrixIds: matrixIds,
      extent: [44.03, 23.34, 63.34, 39.78]
    })
```

You should also check the WMTS capabilities document to ensure you have the correct settings for the tilegrid as many systems use two tiles at level zero for EPSG:4326.

**UPDATE**

The capabilities document shows the EPSG:4326 grid is 2 tiles wide (Min 0, Max 1) at level 0, so to use that you would need

```
resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z + 1);
```

The capabilities also gives a more precise extent which you should use

```
extent: [45.5891647338867, 26.974308013916, 57.2815895080566, 36.8526191711426]
```

The service also supports EPSG:900913 (which is equivalent to EPSG:3857) and that does have one tile at level 0.  To use that you could change all occurrences of EPSG:4326 in your code to EPSG:900913 then use

```
extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([45.5891647338867, 26.974308013916, 57.2815895080566, 36.8526191711426], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913')
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, But It didn't work these are links of my layer, https://pastebin.pl/view/b3267a53 and this is my layer xml in geoserver https://pastebin.pl/view/32f3441b is that because geoserver wmts configuration?

Comment: I still get this error https://pastebin.pl/view/5e834ea2

Comment: Sorry Mike I took your time, I did update my code based on your description https://pastebin.pl/view/490d7a85 but I got that error but in different min and max https://pastebin.pl/view/7b0e8309

Comment: This one https://pastebin.pl/view/8c175609 didn't return error in console but I didn't show map https://imgur.com/QRlvW3i

Comment: Use `resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z + 1);` only for EPSG:4326.  If you change to 900913 `resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);` will be correct.

Comment: Hmm I did, but When I use extent in simple mode without  extent: ol.proj.transformExtent I didn't get error but when I use  extent: ol.proj.transformExtent I get error in https://imgur.com/undefined if I paste that link on browser I'll get https://imgur.com/QZiKfQD

Comment: You first imgur link is not working.  Without the transform the extent in EPSG:900913 is just a box 11 meters across in the Atlantic close to the equator, so unless you map was centered there nothing would be requested.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mike my issue solved, I cleared GeoServer Cache Tile and I did try to cached layer renew, I did delete all chached layer in Tile Layers, Thank you so much Mike God Bless You

Comment: Mike I've a tiny problem, some parts of my map did disappear could you please help me where should I change var map or extent?https://imgur.com/ECg0tbd and https://imgur.com/bcC9JIO, I should mention all maps are in EPSG:4326

Comment: Try increasing the extent, for example to [44.03, 23.34, 63.34, 39.78]